# Variable passing throwing error in BigQueryInsertJobOperator in Airflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have written a BigQueryInsertJobOperator in Airflow to select and insert data to a Big Query table. But I am facing issue with variable passing. I am getting below error while executing Airflow DAG.

> File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/query.py", line 911, in to_api_repr
> configuration = self._configuration.to_api_repr()
> File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/query.py", line 683, in to_api_repr
> query_parameters = resource["query"].get("queryParameters")
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Here is my Operator code:

```
dag = DAG(
'bq_to_sql_operator', 
default_args=default_args, 
schedule_interval="@daily",
template_searchpath="/opt/airflow/dags/scripts",
user_defined_macros={"BQ_PROJECT": BQ_PROJECT, "BQ_EDW_DATASET": BQ_EDW_DATASET, "BQ_STAGING_DATASET": BQ_STAGING_DATASET},
catchup=False
)

t1 = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
    task_id='bq_write_to_umc_cg_service_agg_stg',
    configuration={
        "query": "{% include 'umc_cg_service_agg_stg.sql' %}",
        "useLegacySql":False,
        "allow_large_results":True,
        "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE", 
        "destinationTable": {
            'projectId': BQ_PROJECT,
            'datasetId': BQ_STAGING_DATASET,
            'tableId': UMC_CG_SERVICE_AGG_STG_TABLE_NAME
        }
    },
    params={'BQ_PROJECT': BQ_PROJECT, 'BQ_EDW_DATASET': BQ_EDW_DATASET, 'BQ_STAGING_DATASET': BQ_STAGING_DATASET },
    gcp_conn_id=BQ_CONN_ID,
    location=BQ_LOCATION,
    dag=dag
)
```

My SQL file looks like as below:

```
select
        faccs2.employer_key employer_key,
        faccs2.service_name service_name,
        gender,
        approximate_age_band,
        state,
        relationship_map_name,
        account_attribute1_name,
        account_attribute1_value,
        account_attribute2_name,
        account_attribute2_value,
        account_attribute3_name,
        account_attribute3_value,
        account_attribute4_name,
        account_attribute4_value,
        account_attribute5_name,
        account_attribute5_value,
        count(distinct faccs2.sf_service_id) total_service_count
    from `{{params.BQ_PROJECT}}.{{params.BQ_EDW_DATASET}}.fact_account_cg_case_survey` faccs
    inner join `{{params.BQ_PROJECT}}.{{params.BQ_EDW_DATASET}}.fact_account_cg_case_service` faccs2 on faccs.sf_case_id = faccs2.sf_case_id
    inner join `{{params.BQ_PROJECT}}.{{params.BQ_EDW_DATASET}}.dim_account` da on faccs2.account_key = da.account_key
    left join `{{params.BQ_PROJECT}}.{{params.BQ_STAGING_DATASET}}.stg_account_selected_attr_tmp2` attr on faccs.account_key = attr.account_key
    where not da.is_test_account_flag
    and attr.gender is not null
    and coalesce(faccs.case_status,'abc') <> 'Closed as Duplicate'
    group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16;
```

Can someone please help me how to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you provide the complete operator code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the query configuration should be in a nested document called `query`:

```py
t1 = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
    task_id='bq_write_to_umc_cg_service_agg_stg',
    configuration={
        "query": {
            "query": "{% include 'umc_cg_service_agg_stg.sql' %}",
            "useLegacySql":False,
            "allow_large_results":True,
            "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE", 
            "destinationTable": {
                'projectId': BQ_PROJECT,
                'datasetId': BQ_STAGING_DATASET,
                'tableId': UMC_CG_SERVICE_AGG_STG_TABLE_NAME
            }
        }
    },
    params={'BQ_PROJECT': BQ_PROJECT, 'BQ_EDW_DATASET': BQ_EDW_DATASET, 'BQ_STAGING_DATASET': BQ_STAGING_DATASET },
    gcp_conn_id=BQ_CONN_ID,
    location=BQ_LOCATION,
    dag=dag
)
```

With your provided configuration dict, an internal method try to access `queryParameters` which should be in the dict `configuration["query"]`, but it finds str instead of dict.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below script what I've used at work.

```py
    target_date = '{{ ds_nodash }}'

    ...

    # DAG task
    t1= bq.BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
        task_id = 'sample_task,
        configuration = {
            "query": {
                "query": f"{{% include 'your_query_file.sql' %}}",
                "useLegacySql": False,
                "queryParameters": [
                    { "name": "target_date", 
                      "parameterType": { "type": "STRING" },
                      "parameterValue": { "value": f"{target_date}" }
                    }
                ],
                "parameterMode": "NAMED"
            },
        },
        location = 'asia-northeast3',
    )
```

```sql
-- in your_query_file.sql, @target_date value is passed as a named parameter.

DECLARE target_date DATE DEFAULT SAFE.PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @target_date);

SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE partitioned_at = target_date;
```

You can refer to **configuration** JSON field specification on the link below.

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query#queryrequest

> **parameterMode** string
>
> Standard SQL only. Set to POSITIONAL to use positional (?) query parameters or to **NAMED** *to use named (@myparam) query parameters in this query*.

> queryParameters[]  object (**QueryParameter**)
>
> jobs.query parameters for Standard SQL queries.

**queryParameters** is an array of **QueryParameter** which has following JSON format.

```json
{
  "name": string,
  "parameterType": {
    object (QueryParameterType)
  },
  "parameterValue": {
    object (QueryParameterValue)
  }
}
```

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/QueryParameter